# "ones and others"

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses

> ***The ones who wake up lose their memories of the tale, while the ones who don’t remain in a coma for the rest of their lives.***

As I take a cursory glance at this sentence, I can notice that something is not right.

That will be in independent clause of the sentence, which states, **"while the ones who don't remain in com ...."**.

If I were the writer of the sentence, I would write the clause as ***"while the others remain in a coma for the rest of their lives "***.

Since being taken from a reliable source and seeming quite cryptic to me, I wanted to know a correct form of the clause...

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, "while" is used as a coordinating conjunction between two independent clauses:
The ones who wake up lose their memories of the tale.
The ones who don't [wake up] remain in a coma...

Here is a definition with a similar use of "while":
[American Heritage Dictionary "while" (3)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=while)
3. And on the contrary: *The soles are leather, while the uppers are canvas.*

As you can see in this example sentence, both clauses are independent.
Here, "while" has the same sense as "but", as a coordinating conjunction.

Your rewritten sentence is good, but it isn't necessary, and it also consists of two independent clauses linked by a coordinating conjunction.

Comment: I think you are referring to "don't" not having  "wake up" after it. But it would be possible to separate the clauses as two sentences, and use "don't", or "do not" as a verb, with the understanding of the omitted part carried over from the first sentence.